# pyspark - get first non null attribute from Struct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an array of struct defined in my schema where the value attribute could be a string, int, float or boolean.

```
printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- custom_fields: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- member0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- member1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- member2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- member3: boolean (nullable = true)
```

And the input example:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "custom_fields": [{
            "id": 123,
            "value": True
        },
        {
            "id": 456,
            "value": "awesome"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have a kind of mapping to convert those custom fields IDs to friendly names. As mapping example:

```
{
    123: 'has_bugs',
    456: 'type'
}
```

My problem: I'm build an expressions list to perform a flatten to avoid nested structures and have friendly names instead of an array of custom_fields:

```
cf_dict_mapping = { 123: 'has_bugs', 456: 'type' }
cf_spark_map = map_from_entries("custom_fields")
exprs = [cf_spark_map.getItem(i).cast("string").alias(t) for i, t in cf_dict_mapping.items()]

df = df.select(*["*"] + exprs)
```

This code is almost working but instead of return something like `"has_bugs: true"`, it's returning `"has_bugs: ['true', '', '', '']"`.

How can I make my code get first "memberX" from `custom_fields` that is not null?

edit: I have tried with `coalesce` but it won't work `[coalesce(cf_spark_map.getItem(i).cast("string")).alias(t) for i, t in cf_dict_mapping.items()]`.

Comment: `coalesce(*[cf_spark_map.getItem(i).cast("string").alias(t) for i, t in cf_dict_mapping.items()])`? (move the coalesce outside of the list comp)

Comment: @pault `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [*]`

Comment: Your input example doesn't correspond to the schema. Can you edit your question and add a complete example so that we could reproduce it?